# Proof of expected time to failure for a "k out of n" system, each component IID exponentially distributed

Tags: statistics, expected-value, order-statistics, reliability

A "k out of n" system functions if, as the name suggests, *k* of the *n* components of the system remain operational, i.e. the system fails upon failure of any *n-k+1* components.

My A/S/M MAS-I study manual (1st edition, 4th print) states without proof: for a *k* out of *n* system with components having identical exponentially distributed survival times with mean *θ*, expected time to failure is

$$ \theta \sum_{i=k}^n \frac{1}{i} $$

I'm stuck on proving this. A/S/M doesn't really cite sources and my searches on this site and others have come up short. I appreicate the help!

Answer (score 0):

One of the reading materials for the exam provided me the answer: Introduction to Probability Models by Sheldon M. Ross, p.590 http://files.kevinl.io/introduction-to-prob-models-11th-edition.PDF

The exponential distribution gives distribution function $F(t)= 1 - e^{-t/\theta}$ and survival function $S(t)=e^{-t/\theta}$ for each component, so we have a joint survival function for the system given by

$$S(t)={\sum_{i=k}^n}\binom{n}{i}(e^{-t/\theta})^{i}(1-e^{-t/\theta})^{n-i}$$

The support of our distribution is non-negative so we can use ${E(t)=\int_{0}^\infty} S(t)dt$ to calculate the expected time to failure. Thus

$$E(t)={\int_{0}^\infty}{\sum_{i=k}^n}\binom{n}{i}(e^{-t/\theta})^{i}(1-e^{-t/\theta})^{n-i}dt$$
$$={\sum_{i=k}^n}\binom{n}{i}{\int_{0}^\infty}(e^{-t/\theta})^{i}(1-e^{-t/\theta})^{n-i}dt$$

Substituting $u=e^{-t/\theta}$, $du=-\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-t/\theta}dt$ gives

$$E(t)=\theta{\sum_{i=k}^n} \binom{n}{i}{\int_{0}^1}u^{i-1}(1-u)^{n-i}dt$$

Embarrassingly this is where I got stuck but letting $C(y;a,b)=\int_{0}^1y^a(1-y)^bdy$, it is easily shown that $C(y;a,0)=\frac{1}{a+1}$, and via integration by parts $C(y;a,b)=\frac{b}{a+1}C(y;a+1,b-1)$. From these two relations induction gives $C(y;a,b)=\frac{a!b!}{(a+b+1)!}$.

Alternatively it could be noted that $f(y)=\frac{\Gamma(a+b+2)}{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}y^a(1-y)^b$ is the density function of a Beta distribution with positive integer parameters *a+1* and *b+1*, and since we must have $\int_{0}^1f(y)dy=1$, then $\int_{0}^1C(y;a,b)dy=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+b+2)}=\frac{a!b!}{(a+b+1)!}$.

In either case we can now produce

$$E(t)=\theta{\sum_{i=k}^n} \binom{n}{i}{\int_{0}^1}u^{i-1}(1-u)^{n-i}dt$$
$$=\theta{\sum_{i=k}^n}\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\frac{(i-1)!(n-i)!}{n!}$$
$$=\theta{\sum_{i=k}^n}\frac{1}{i}$$